# Trying to get two different fig captions side by side in a container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get two separate fig captions side by side instead of one on top of the other, every time i tryed it would just move the teaxtarea.

```css
textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #262626;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}


img {
    display: block;
}

.container {
  
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 93.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: 0.5rem auto #4d90fe;
}

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

/* Profile Section */

.profile {
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

.profile::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.profile-user-settings,
.profile-stats,
.profile-bio {
    float: left;
    width: calc(66.666% - 2rem);
}

.profile-user-settings {
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
}

.profile-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-edit-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    border: 0.1rem solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0 2.4rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}





.profile-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-stats li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}



.profile-real-name,
.profile-stat-count,
.profile-edit-btn {
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Gallery Section */

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: -1rem -1rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery-item {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 22rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-info,
.gallery-item:focus .gallery-item-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.gallery-item-info {
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item-info li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.gallery-item-likes {
    margin-right: 2.2rem;
}

.gallery-item-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.fa-clone,
.fa-comment {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.gallery-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



/* Media Query */

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
    .profile {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 4rem 0;
    }

    .profile::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    .profile-user-settings {
        flex-basis: calc(100% - 10.7rem);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-user-name {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        order: 1;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .profile-bio {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .profile-stats {
        order: 1;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-stats ul {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1.2rem 0;
        border-top: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
    }

    .profile-stats li {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .profile-stat-count {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Spinner Animation */

@keyframes loader {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

/*

The following code will only run if your browser supports CSS grid.

Remove or comment-out the code block below to see how the browser will fall-back to flexbox & floated styling. 

*/

@supports (display: grid) {
    .profile {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-column-gap: 3rem;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .profile-image {
        grid-row: 1 / -1;
    }

    .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(22rem, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 2rem;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-stats,
    .profile-bio,
    .gallery-item,
    .gallery {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 40rem) {
        .profile {
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
        }

        .profile-image {
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .profile-user-settings {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }

        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-stats,
        .profile-bio {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }

        .profile-user-settings,
        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-settings-btn,
        .profile-bio,
        .profile-stats {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200,300,800);
@import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
figure.snip0056 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 380px;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure.snip0056 > img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6);
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: -15%;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption {
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2,
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons i {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a {
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 .position {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 1;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  clear: both;
}
figure.snip0056.blue .position {
  background: #20638f;
}
figure.snip0056.red .position {
  background: #962d22;
}
figure.snip0056.yellow .position {
  background: #bf6516;
}
figure.snip0056:hover > img,
figure.snip0056.hover > img {
  right: -12%;
}
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

#social {
  position: absolute;
  right:    0;
  bottom:   0;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.smGlobalBtn { /* global button class */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border:2px solid #ddd; /* add border to the buttons */
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #999;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 27px;
    -moz-border-radius:27px;
    -webkit-border-radius:27px;
}

/* facebook button class*/
.facebookBtn{
    background: #4060A5;
}

.facebookBtn:before{ /* use :before to add the relevant icons */
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f09a"; /* add facebook icon */
}

.facebookBtn:hover{
    color: #4060A5;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #4060A5; /* change the border color on mouse hover */
}

/* twitter button class*/
.twitterBtn{
    background: #00ABE3;
}

.twitterBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f099"; /* add twitter icon */
      
}

.twitterBtn:hover{
      color: #00ABE3;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #00ABE3;
}


/* instagram button class*/
.instagramBtn{
    background: #4169E1;
}

.instagramBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f16d"; /* add instagram icon */
}

.instagramBtn:hover{
      color: #00FFFF;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #4169E1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">

  <div class="profile">

    <form action="testing.php" method="post">
      <textarea name="text2" rows="2" cols=0> Family Name</textarea><br>
    </form>

    <button class="btn profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>

  </div>
  <!-- End of profile section -->

</div>
<!-- End of container -->

</header>

<main>

  <div class="container">
    <figure class="snip0056">
      <figcaption>
        <textarea name="text2" rows="2" cols=0></textarea>
        <textarea name="text3" rows="8" cols=20>.</textarea>
        </p>

      </figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample8.jpg" alt="profilepic1" />

      <div class="position">
        <textarea name="text4" rows="1" cols=9></textarea>
      </div>
      </h3>
    </figure>
    <figure class="snip0056 yellow">
      <figcaption>
        <textarea name="text5" rows="2" cols=0></textarea>
         <textarea name="text6" rows="8" cols=20></textarea>

      </figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample9.jpg" alt="sample9" />
      <div class="position">
       <textarea name="text4" rows="1" cols=9>Title</textarea>
    </figure>
    <div id="social">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
      <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button&size=small&width=67&height=20&appId" width="67" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: You don't have any `figcaption` next to each other...are you trying make the two `textarea` inside `figcaption` be side-by-side?

Comment: let me rephrase, how do i get the two different objects side by side instead of one optop of the other like they currently are. hope that clears things up

Comment: try `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Tried the white-space: nowrap; and it did what i wanted but only for the text area not the two separate objects sitting on top of each other. let me explain further I have two different figure classes on top of each other figure class="snipe0056" & figure class="snipe0056 yellow" I simply want them next to each other and not on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example you can do it by adding `display: flex;` into `.container` style or `white-space: nowrap;` into `.container` and `display: inline-block;` into `figure` styles:

```css
/* this */
.container
{
  display: flex;
}

/* or this */

/*
.container
{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

figure
{
  display: inline-block;
}
*/




textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #262626;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}


img {
    display: block;
}

.container {
  
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 93.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: 0.5rem auto #4d90fe;
}

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

/* Profile Section */

.profile {
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

.profile::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.profile-user-settings,
.profile-stats,
.profile-bio {
    float: left;
    width: calc(66.666% - 2rem);
}

.profile-user-settings {
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
}

.profile-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-edit-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    border: 0.1rem solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0 2.4rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}





.profile-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-stats li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}



.profile-real-name,
.profile-stat-count,
.profile-edit-btn {
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Gallery Section */

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: -1rem -1rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery-item {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 22rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-info,
.gallery-item:focus .gallery-item-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.gallery-item-info {
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item-info li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.gallery-item-likes {
    margin-right: 2.2rem;
}

.gallery-item-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.fa-clone,
.fa-comment {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.gallery-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



/* Media Query */

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
    .profile {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 4rem 0;
    }

    .profile::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    .profile-user-settings {
        flex-basis: calc(100% - 10.7rem);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-user-name {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        order: 1;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .profile-bio {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .profile-stats {
        order: 1;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-stats ul {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1.2rem 0;
        border-top: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
    }

    .profile-stats li {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .profile-stat-count {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Spinner Animation */

@keyframes loader {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

/*

The following code will only run if your browser supports CSS grid.

Remove or comment-out the code block below to see how the browser will fall-back to flexbox & floated styling. 

*/

@supports (display: grid) {
    .profile {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-column-gap: 3rem;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .profile-image {
        grid-row: 1 / -1;
    }

    .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(22rem, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 2rem;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-stats,
    .profile-bio,
    .gallery-item,
    .gallery {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 40rem) {
        .profile {
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
        }

        .profile-image {
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .profile-user-settings {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }

        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-stats,
        .profile-bio {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }

        .profile-user-settings,
        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-settings-btn,
        .profile-bio,
        .profile-stats {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200,300,800);
@import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
figure.snip0056 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 380px;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure.snip0056 > img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6);
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: -15%;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption {
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2,
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons i {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a {
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 .position {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 1;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  clear: both;
}
figure.snip0056.blue .position {
  background: #20638f;
}
figure.snip0056.red .position {
  background: #962d22;
}
figure.snip0056.yellow .position {
  background: #bf6516;
}
figure.snip0056:hover > img,
figure.snip0056.hover > img {
  right: -12%;
}
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

#social {
  position: absolute;
  right:    0;
  bottom:   0;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.smGlobalBtn { /* global button class */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border:2px solid #ddd; /* add border to the buttons */
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #999;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 27px;
    -moz-border-radius:27px;
    -webkit-border-radius:27px;
}

/* facebook button class*/
.facebookBtn{
    background: #4060A5;
}

.facebookBtn:before{ /* use :before to add the relevant icons */
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f09a"; /* add facebook icon */
}

.facebookBtn:hover{
    color: #4060A5;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #4060A5; /* change the border color on mouse hover */
}

/* twitter button class*/
.twitterBtn{
    background: #00ABE3;
}

.twitterBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f099"; /* add twitter icon */
      
}

.twitterBtn:hover{
      color: #00ABE3;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #00ABE3;
}


/* instagram button class*/
.instagramBtn{
    background: #4169E1;
}

.instagramBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f16d"; /* add instagram icon */
}

.instagramBtn:hover{
      color: #00FFFF;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #4169E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="profile">

    <form action="testing.php" method="post">
      <textarea name="text2" rows="2" cols=0> Family Name</textarea><br>
    </form>

    <button class="btn profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>

  </div>
  <!-- End of profile section -->

</div>
<!-- End of container -->

</header>

<main>

  <div class="container">
    <figure class="snip0056">
      <figcaption>
        <textarea name="text2" rows="2" cols=0></textarea>
        <textarea name="text3" rows="8" cols=20>.</textarea>
        </p>

      </figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample8.jpg" alt="profilepic1" />

      <div class="position">
        <textarea name="text4" rows="1" cols=9></textarea>
      </div>
      </h3>
    </figure>
    <figure class="snip0056 yellow">
      <figcaption>
        <textarea name="text5" rows="2" cols=0></textarea>
         <textarea name="text6" rows="8" cols=20></textarea>

      </figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample9.jpg" alt="sample9" />
      <div class="position">
       <textarea name="text4" rows="1" cols=9>Title</textarea>
    </figure>
    <div id="social">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
      <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button&size=small&width=67&height=20&appId" width="67" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </div>

</main>
```